# How to hide import button in odoo tree view (Odoo v12)

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I am working with Odoo v12 and I need to hide the "import" button in a tree view but keeping the create button.

I have tried so far with

```
<tree string="" import ="false">.
```

But the import button is still showing.

How can I hide the import button?

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete the "Import" button in Odoo because it is generated dynamically in the JavaScript code. I would use some sort of group permissions for users you do want not to be able to access.

Another option is to make a custom module to hide the button. Something like this extends the list controller.

```
this.$buttons.find('.o_button_import').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try overriding Javascript like this.

```py
    odoo.define('account.invoice_tree', function (require) {
    "use strict";

    var ListController = require("web.ListController");

    var includeDict = {
        renderButtons: function () {
            this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            if (this.modelName === "account.invoice") {
                this.$buttons.find('button.o_button_upload_bill').hide();
            }
        }
    };

    ListController.include(includeDict);
    });
```

and be sure to include your script in the assets list:

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/hr_account/static/src/js/invoice_tree.js"></script>
```

This will hide the button. In my example, it was the upload button on the invoice.